# Articles and Categories, m:m is mapped, where to add method to return paged articles?

Tags: nhibernate, oop

I have 2 entities:
Article
Category

I created the mappings so both entities have each others as collections, so:

Article.Categories
Category.Articles

Now, I want to create a method in either ArticleDAO or CategoryDAO to return a paged (subset) of articles.

Which DAO makes sense?

Since the article entity has categories as its collection, does it still make sense to add the method to the articleDAO?

Answer (score 0):

A method that returns a list of Articles should go in your ArticleDAO, regardless of what its properties are.